# Gradle including project as dependency not working

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to create a Gradle project by using multiple subprojects, **util** depends on **api** project, both projects reside under the same directory:

```
├── mainFolder
│   ...
├── api
│   ├── src
│   │   └──...
│   └── build.gradle
├── util
│   ├── src
│   │   └──...
│   └── build.gradle
└── settings.gradle
```

**util project build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'my.package.util'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.7.5'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}")

    implementation project(':api')
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**util project settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'util'
```

**api project build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'my.package.api'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.7.5'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}")

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**api project gradle.settings**

```
rootProject.name = 'api'
```

**main project gradle.settings**

```
include ':api'
include ':util'
```

But after running gradle build I'm always getting this error message:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'util'.
Project with path ':api' could not be found in root project 'util'.
```

I'll appreciate any hint, thanks in advance.

Comment: There’s only one settings.gradle. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

Comment: Removing settings.gradle for individual projects ends also with an error:

Execution failed for task ':util:bootJar'.
> Error while evaluating property 'mainClass' of task ':util:bootJar'
   > Failed to calculate the value of task ':util:bootJar' property 'mainClass'.
      > Main class name has not been configured and it could not be resolved

Comment: `org.springframework.boot` plugin should be applied only to projects that contain a Springboot application (project containing a @SpringbootApplication annoted main class).  Is your `util` subproject really a Springboot app project, or just a utility java library project?

Comment: There are literally hundreds of examples for spring boot Gradle multi module projects, including one from spring team https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/

Comment: @M.Ricciuti is just a library project.

Answer (score 0):

I missed some configurations and removed unnecessary libraries from the **build.gradle** file followed this basic [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module).